# Is it possible to write a bash script that changes the current directory to a random one?

Tags: bash, terminal

Of course there would be little to no point to this, but the idea struck me today and I haven't really seen anything on it. I suppose it could be a good exercise on efficiency, especially if you consider *every* directory under (/).

Comment: A script invoked as a separate executable (as opposed to sourced) can't change the current directory of the shell that calls it at all. Other than that... sure, why not? :)

Comment: Is your question _really_ "is X possible"? If so, there are only two answers, "yes" and "no".

Comment: Perhaps a shell function? Also, I am sure it's possible. It doesn't seem too outlandish, but I was curious to see what people came up with.

Comment: I merely thought that people might find this question interesting to think about. I apologize if it is out of the scope of this site.

Comment: Code golf and programming puzzles got kicked out of StackOverflow a long time ago. See http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ for a site where this kind of question is in-scope.

Answer (score 0):

First idea that comes to mind:

Pipe a recursive ls command to a file, use wc to count number of lines, then generate a random integer and use it to pick a line from the file you just created.

ls -R / >> file_list.txt
count=$(wc -l file_list.txt)

etc. You can get it from here.

Comment: This is a dangerous idea for a few reasons. First, `ls` doesn't write filenames in a way that's guaranteed to be usable if you read it back and pass it to `cd`; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: If you NUL-delimited your names, that would at least be safe, but you'd want to use, say, `find / -type d -print0`, not `ls`.

Comment: Second -- think about a filename that contains a literal newline; depending on the details of the local platform's implementation of `ls`; either it would emit a value which wouldn't exactly match any name, and which couldn't be `cd`'d to, or -- worse -- it would emit two separate lines, each with part of the filename.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't actually do the work. I just wanted to give a quick method.  That said, find can give you some weird output, too, particularly if you have space characters in file or directory names.

Perhaps a recursive crawler would be faster and better.

Comment: With `-print0`, no, `find` won't ever give output that doesn't byte-for-byte match a filename (followed by a NUL). If you wanted to provide a reproducer for any contrary assertion, I'd be very much interested to see it. :)

Comment: Okee-doke.
`mkdir "$(echo -e "hello\nnewline")"
find ./ -name h* -print0`

So, in this case, the return is exactly as you say, but, it will still break everything because it comes back on two lines.

Comment: No, it doesn't break "everything". It breaks only things that don't exclusively honor the NUL delimiter (defeating the purpose of using it in the first place). Iterate over output with `IFS= read -r -d ''` or `xargs -0` or an awk/Python/whatever script built to split on NULs and it works perfectly.